# Disable the 'implicit target' on Subversion commit command

Tags: svn, version-control

When using the subversion command-line client, if I issue an `svn commit -m"<Some message>"` without specifying any files, the default behaviour is to commit all modified files in the current directory.

This is referred to in the Subversion manual as an  ["implicit target"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html)

Sometimes when I only want to commit selected files I forget to specify them, causing all files to be checked in inadvertently.

Git doesn't have this implicit target behaviour, You have to specify `git push --all`.

Is it possible to disable the implicit target behaviour in subversion?

Comment: Don't use `-m`, or set up a shell alias?